# How do I add another type of task to the same hierarchy level in Azure DevOps?

Tags: task, hierarchy, personalization

is there a possibility in Azure DevOps to add another work item on the same layer as task and bug as a third option to choose from during the process?

Thank you.

User's image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hyeD.png)

I created a new work item additionally to 'task' and 'bug' and was hoping i could add it to the same hierarchy level, so i could choose it like in the picture below. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd5CZ.png)